# Nonintegral terms in Puiseux series

Tags: power-series

I know that an algebraic function has a Puiseux series expansion around every point. What does it mean when such a Puiseux series doesn't have any nonintegral powers? Can we say anything about such an algebraic function?

Comment: I would have thought it means you have a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the reply. So if you have a Laurent series around every point, does it mean the function is actually just a rational function (fraction of two polynomials)?

Comment: As usual the case $k=\Bbb{C}$ is easier to understand:

For $f\in \overline{\Bbb{C}(z)}$, for every $a$ there is some $n=n_a$ such that $f(a+(z-a)^n)$ is meromorphic at $a$, it has a Laurent expansion, giving the Puiseux series in $(z-a)^{1/n}$ of $f$. If every $n_a=1$ then $f$ is in $\Bbb{C}(z)$, this is because it extends to a meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere. The conjugates of $f$ are its analytic continuations along closed loops.

Comment: @reuns Does this mean that if I can show that no nonintegral terms occur in the Puiseux series at every point, then $n_a = 1$ for every $a$ and so $f$ is meromorphic on the Riemann sphere?

Comment: I overlooked that **every** Puiseux series of $f$ must be meromorphic at $a$, for example $((1+z)^{1/2}+1)^{1/2}$ is meromorphic at $0$ in the branch where $(1+z)^{1/2}-1$ vanishes at $0$ but not in the branch where $(1+z)^{1/2}+1$ vanishes. It is unclear if there is an example of a non-rational algebraic function with some meromorphic branch for every $a$.